# Apache Camel Multipart Netty Rest DSL not working with camel-jackson dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to read multipart/form-data using netty4-http. The problem occurs when I have added dependencies of camel-jackson and camel-xstream in my project which results in JsonParseException which ideally should not happen since we are reading multipart/form-data. Can anyone help me on this?

The code is simple,

```
rest().post("/hello")
            .consumes("multipart/form-data")
            .produces("application/json")
            .to("direct:inbound");

from("direct:inbound")
            .routeId("inbound_email")
            .process(new PayloadParser())
            .process(exchange -> System.out.println("In Body : " + exchange.getIn().getBody()))
            .to("log:ie").end();
```

The error goes like this,

```
2018-05-09 21:24:48.708 DEBUG 31824 --- [ntExecutorGroup] o.a.c.component.netty4.NettyConsumer     : Channel: [id: 0x198248e0, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65379] received body: HttpObjectAggregator$AggregatedFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: CompositeByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 9147, cap: 9147, components=3))
POST /hello HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
tenantid: 2a721265-bd98-45ec-abc3-f8e81c59e257
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------269100026150164898107684
Content-Length: 9147
2018-05-09 21:24:48.743 DEBUG 31824 --- [ntExecutorGroup] o.a.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-GSHYD-C02T823UG8WN-local-1525881280467-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-GSHYD-C02T823UG8WN-local-1525881280467-0-1). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]
```

Comment: This exception comes probably from output marshalling, not from input. Since you have added `.produces("application/json")`, Camel automatically tries to convert it to json, if any converter available. If you have handled marshalling yourself, remove `produces()`. Or you can try `.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)`, but right now iam not sure if it have precedence over content-type.

Comment: I debugged it and found that its infact marshalling the input, also tried removing the `.produces("application/json")`. The body starts with boundary value `----7234` and its unable to convert this to a Json output. With `RestBindingMode.off` I need to specify `marshall()` and `unmarshall()` everywhere. The http content-type attribute is not honoured in this case and looks like a bug.

Comment: Which Camel version you are using? And do you have components in same version as Camel Core?

Comment: camel.version = 2.21.1, all components share the same version

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have malformed data in your JSON payload -- without knowing for certain what you are trying to do -- it seems the parser is processing a field it expects to be cast as a number but it contains a dash (-).

It's all right there in the error message:

"2018-05-09 21:24:48.743 DEBUG 31824 --- [ntExecutorGroup] o.a.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-GSHYD-C02T823UG8WN-local-1525881280467-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-GSHYD-C02T823UG8WN-local-1525881280467-0-1). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: **Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value**
"

Comment: But its a multipart/form-data, Json should not be the default message translator. If I remove camel-jackson from maven dependency things are working as expected.